# What is the difference between Clone and Import in Build definition?

Tags: build, azure-devops

I see an option to import a build definition from a json file and create the definition.

Also there is an option to clone a build definition from the existing definition.

[image]
so what is the difference between the above in VSTS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clone** - VSTS build definition we have useful option "Clone.." which allows duplicate entire definition. It will be more useful to clone build step within saved build definition. Clone allows you to take the existing one and make a copy to make further modifications. Clone step can be done directly by CTRL+Click and drag/drop that task/step.

**Import** - Import option build definitions is useful for recreating all the build steps, variables, schedules, etc in a same or different team project. i. e import allows you to get it from another project or somewhere outside

Answer (score 1):

Cloning makes a direct copy within the same team project, all within the UI.

Export/import allows you to export/import the raw JSON file that defines the build, which is useful if you want to share the build definition across team projects or accounts, if you want to do big changes that are difficult to do via the UI, or even if you want to script or otherwise automate changing or creating build definitions.